# What are the design trade-offs between a pusher and a puller propeller?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller

Wich is the difference in having the propeller forward or back in an airplane.

I would like to know the technical differences like in a Piaggio 180 or in a normal Cessna.

Comment: Technical differences is very broad, you mean in structural, aerodynamic, flying characteristics? Something else?

Comment: I mean during the projecting phase..

Comment: The difference that can make to choose a solution than another

Comment: Ty right! Ty all !